# Why does <img src= ' '/> not working on express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I was studying on html and it was simply img src="...."
but on express, something different and only img src="...." didn't work!
Document says I need to put them in folder named public then require('path') and app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
I don't understand why difference should be exist between them.

Comment: Express is a Nodejs framework, it runs on a server. `<img>` is HTML, it runs in a browser, on a different machine altogether. If you write `<img src="myImage.jpg">`, then the browser will make a network request to this URL (the full URL being `http://localhost/myImage.jpg`). Your Node server (augmented with Express, if you use the Express framework) will then treat this request, look in your `/public` folder, find the image, and send it back to the browser to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with HTML vs Express. This is HTML + whatever you used instead of Express vs HTML + Express.

The `src` attribute has to point to the URL of the image.

If you are writing an HTTP server in Express, then you need to write code to give the image a URL. The `static` middleware is the standard way to do that for static files, like most images, with Express.

If you are using some pre-written web server with support for static files (or just reading directly from the file system) then they will take care of giving the image a URL for you.

Comment: Sorry, Im so new to studying on those..I don't understand.. when I write html, I only <img src=" "/> then on the chrome, image shows up but when I working on express and node, it didn't

Comment: @John — You said that in the question. This answer explains why.

Comment: Oh, I just understood your answer.. thanks a lot!